# if statement with more than one condition

Tags: javascript

I need to check three conditions,

> ```
> sheet_exists = 1
> recalc = 1 
> qty_total and new_qty_total are not equal
> ```

The if statement works well if only the first 2 arguments are used:

```
if(sheet_exists === 1 && recalc === 'yes'){
   //do something
}
```

But when I try to add he 3rd argument it fails, the actions in the if statement are ignored. I've tried:

```
if((sheet_exists === 1) && (recalc === 'yes') && (qty_total !== new_qty_total)){
   //do something
}
```

And:

```
if(sheet_exists === 1 && recalc === 'yes' && (qty_total !== new_qty_total)){
    //do something
}
```

And:

```
if(sheet_exists === 1 && recalc === 'yes' && qty_total !== new_qty_total){
    //do something
 }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: All are valid, though the third is the most correct in this case. What is it exactly that doesnt work well?

Comment: Are you saying this shouldn't work https://jsfiddle.net/x2s89pnv/

Comment: Would be great if you can create a fiddle.

Comment: What are the types of `qty_total` and `new_qty_total` ?

Comment: @Andreas: yup...OP needs to parse the values to same format for doing strict comparison.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `qty_total` and `new_qty_total` have different values? Have you tried logging them to the console/walking the code in the debugger?

Comment: @JLRishe, yes I have

Comment: @tatty27 Well, Dr.Avalanche's fiddle demonstrates that there is nothing wrong with the code you've shown us, so the problem is somewhere else. Unless you provide us a reproducible scenario, I don't think there's much more anyone can do.

Comment: Be sure that values of data. Check them again.

Answer (score -2):

Considering you are happy with the behavior of the first two conditions, and not with the last one, the problem must be in the last one.

Pay attention, `qty_total !== new_qty_total` will return `TRUE` only when the value **or type** of `qty_total` and `new_qty_total` are different.

If one is an integer `100` and the other is a string `'100'` then the condition evaluates as `TRUE` because they differ on the data type. But if they are both integers it will return FALSE, because neither the value nor the type are different.

To make sure the comparison works ok, make sure both variables are the same data type.

Comment: This entire answer is incorrect except for the first line. I think you're confusing the `!==` operator with the `===` operator.

Comment: You are right, I got confused. If I'm not mistaken now it should be more correct.

Comment: It's more accurate than it was before, but how is it a solution to OP's problem?

Comment: hi, thanks, both values are integers and if I run an if statement with just the last argument that statement works, it is only when I combine all three arguments it doesn't work